# How to understand custom java framework

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am working on a custom swing based product having its own framework. There is no documentation available for the framework. I want to understand how can I understand the architecture of product and framework.

There are 10s of thousands of java files, so i am getting puzzled. Need your help!

Comment: Can you run JavaDoc on it?

Comment: No i cannot, as there is no javadoc comments written in it

Comment: I have one word for you, one word... RUN!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tools like [Structure 101](http://structure101.com/) or [Degraph](http://schauder.github.io/degraph/) to get an overall overview of the structure and important classes (the ones lot of stuff depends on).

If it is well coded the package structure and names will give you some hint.

If you want to get more detailed insight, I recommend identifying something that gets triggered by the ui, like a button listener, maybe a worker, or something that extends JPanel/JForm or the like. But a break point there and let the debugger give you a tour through the application from the UI through the business logic to the database and back.

Also running some analysis on the version control system to find the stuff that is very stable vs the stuff that got changed a lot lately might be useful.

Comment: Also, seating behind a user might give you precious insights. Sometimes huge parts of an application are not even used.

Comment: It's a huge code base with no comments..... I doubt it will be well designed...

Comment: Huge is a bad sign. No comments is actually better then lots of bad comments (which is the norm in what I see).

Comment: @Jens, thanks much for such valuable info !

Answer (score 1):

Run Javadoc - even though there are no comments, the generated documentation will let you easily browse the relationship between the various classes.

Look for design patterns in the names of the classes (e.g. are there classes with names like FooController or BarDao).

Is this a framework or a functioning application (you said it was a framework but just making sure, hard to believe someone would write a framework with 10K+ classes and not provide any documentation?!?!???)?  If it's a functioning application, identify the model and try to understand the relationship between the various entities.  I often find that once you understand the datamodel, everything else falls into place.

Frameworks typically fall into two categories - ones that provide you with a bunch of code that you use (e.g. Spring) or ones that you provide code that it uses (e.g. Struts).  Try and determine which one you're looking at.  The presence of abstract classes with no (meaningful) concrete subclasses usually signals the latter and those classes would be the extension points.  I find the former is a bit more free-form and can be used more a la carte thus harder to get a grasp on what the key features are.  For example, in Spring, if we stripped names like "core" from JARs and packages and burned the documentation, it would be somewhat difficult to determine that it's primarily a DI framework and not, say, a hodgepodge of utilities - until you stumble onto BeanFactory and see it's (rather large) class hierarchy.

If you have access to the source repository, look at some of the earlier commits - those will likely be the core classes.  As the project matures, the commits will start focusing on peripheral classes.

If this is a functioning application and not a pure framework, you can always use the debugger to step through code and the event mechanism and use that to discern the core classes.

Are there configuration files?  When I'm trying to learn a new piece of software (or a phone or a DVD player), I find the settings are the quickest way to discover features.  Config files would be the equivalent for something like this.

I hope some of this is helpful.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Rand for your valuable comments, really appreciate !

Answer (score 0):

Look at the (JUnit) test cases. Even better, if there are specifications (like in Spock), check these.

This probably does not exist. So if you make your way through the existing source, write these: If you have to maintain the code, do write tests *before*, and *take the time* to have a decent coverage of the existing behaviour before extending it. Depending on the legal situation, I would even consider to get an approval that the coverage of your testcases is accepted.